# How to change cancel button text and font in Google Place Autocomplete?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api, uisearchbar

I use "Place Autocomplete" for my app.
please help me.
I want to change :

1 - cancel button text and font
2 - Primary text font and Secondary text font
3 - Error and message text font
4 - "Try Again" button text and font
[image]

```
import UIKit
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Present the Autocomplete view controller when the button is pressed.
  @IBAction func autocompleteClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

  // Handle the user's selection.
  func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
  }

  // User canceled the operation.
  func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
  func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
  }

  func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
  }

}
```

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#add_a_full-screen_control

Comment: check this again https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller,   https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GMSAutocompleteViewController` doesn't support changing the font of UI elements, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

One way to change the font of the table view in the dialog is by using objective c swizzling

```
 @implementation GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource(ae_custom_font)

-(UITableViewCell *) ae_swizzle_tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell =  [self ae_swizzle_tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([(UILabel*)cell.subviews[0].subviews[0] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    ((UILabel*)cell.subviews[0].subviews[0]).font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    return cell;
}

@end

@interface AutoCompleteVC: GMSAutocompleteViewController
@end

@implementation AutoCompleteVC

-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token,  ^{
        SEL cellForRowSelector = @selector(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:);
        SEL customCellForRowSelector = @selector(ae_swizzle_tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:);
        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource class], cellForRowSelector);
        Method extendedMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource class], customCellForRowSelector);
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, extendedMethod);
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use appearance proxy to modify things about the GMSAutocompleteViewController

These will change the placeholder text with color black, and also the cancel button to black.

```
    let blackColorAttribute: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.black]
    let attributePlaceHolder = NSAttributedString(string: "Ingrese dirección", attributes: blackColorAttribute)
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = attributePlaceHolder
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(blackColorAttribute, for: .normal)
```